# How to produce/generate a .pdb (debug symbols)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, debug-symbols

I'm using Unity. I've loaded an open source Node editor pluggin for it from [here](https://github.com/Baste-RainGames/Node_Editor). My problem is - this pluggin folder does not contain any .pdb, so I cannot debug.
What I've checked/tried:

- My solution configuration in Visual studio is set to "Debug".
- I've downloaded & tried to use "master" & "develop" branch of this plugin from git.

How can I get/produce a .pdb for this code to be able to debug it?

**PS:** (*May be it's relevant to my issue*) I've noticed, that only few of .cs files are shown in Solution explorer in Visual studio:

[image: SolutionExplorer without any .cs files from Framework folder]

for example, none of framework files are present in Solution explorer:

[image: These .cs files in Framework folder are present in OS file explorer]

Comment: Did you try this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yash/2007/10/12/pdb-files-what-are-they-and-how-to-generate-them/

Comment: @SouvikGhosh, now yes - it's looks like Ok there ("...\output\Debug Info" is set to pdb-only)

Answer (score 0):

I'll not accept this answer, 'cos it doesn't actually *answer* my initial question.
*But* it solved my particular problem (actual only for Unity), so I post it:

My actual problem was an inability to debug code because of non-working breakpoints with message: "*The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.*":
[image: non-working breakpoint demonstration]

And it was solved by simple using "Debug \ Attach Unity debugger" instead of familar to me "Debug \ Attach to Process" in Visual Studio =)